# Laravel, MognoDB. Не работает параметр unique - дублируются значения в базе

Tags: laravel, mongodb

В БД записываются данные которые дублируются, хотя в миграции стоит параметр `unique` для данного поля.

Модель:

```
 class Note extends Eloquent
{
protected $connection = 'mongodb';
protected $collection = 'notes';
protected $fillable = [
    'caption', 'text', 'parent_id'
];
}
```

Функция `Up` в миграции:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::connection('mongodb')->create('notes', function (Blueprint $collection) {
        $collection->increments('id');
        $collection->string('caption')->unique();
        $collection->longText('text');
        $collection->string('parent_id')->nullable();
        $collection->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Не очень очевидно почему так

Comment: попробуйте вместо `$collection->string('caption')->unique();` сделать `$collection->unique('caption');`

Comment: @n.osennij, да, сработало, спасибо! Хотя странно - аналогичный код под MySql ` $collection->string('caption')->unique();` выдаёт ошибку при дубляже. 
Добавте как ответ

Comment: `db.notes.getIndexes();` смотрите через консоль. должно быть `... "unique" : true, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте вместо

`$collection->string('caption')->unique();`

сделать

`$collection->unique('caption');`

Comment: мне кстати не понятно все еще, почему первый вариант нерабочий, вроде работало же раньше так

Comment: чёрт знает. Особенности mongo. Может баг какой или ещё что.